# My response data return " kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@1493a74"

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to do dictionary app using kotlin language. I built the project with mvvm and clean architecture. I have been trying to pull vocabulary information from the internet using jsoap. I am using flow for data. I couldnt find where the issiue is. Normally, the words should appear on the screen or I should be able to see the data when I println on the console.But I can't see it on the screen or on the console, probably because the data coming from the internet is as follows.

```
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@1493a74
```

I am sharing my codes below

**ExtractedData**

```
data class ExtractedData(
    var id :Int = 0,
    var word:String = "",
    var meaning :String = ""
)
```

I created `ExtractedData` class to represent vocabulary or word data from internet

**WordInfoRepositoryImpl**

```
class WordInfoRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api:DictionaryApi
) : WordInfoRepository {

  
    //get words with meanings on the internet using jsoap

    override fun getEventsList(): Flow<Resource<MutableList<ExtractedData>>> = flow {



            emit(Resource.Loading())

            val listData = mutableListOf<ExtractedData>()


            try {
                val url = "https://ielts.com.au/australia/prepare/article-100-new-english-words-and-phrases-updated-2020"


                val doc = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                    Jsoup.connect(url).get()//-->Here it gives the following warning even though I have it in withContext `Inappropriate blocking method call` 
                }

                val table = doc.select("table")
                val rows = table.select("tr")
                val eventsSize = rows.size


                for (i in 1 until eventsSize) {
                    val row = rows[i]
                    val cols = row.select("td")
                    val word = cols[0].text()
                    val meaning = cols[1].text()

                    listData.add(ExtractedData(i,word,meaning))

                }

            }
            catch (e: IOException) {
                emit(Resource.Error("IO Exception"))
            }
            catch (e : HttpException) {
                emit(Resource.Error("HTTP EXCEPTION"))
            }


            emit(Resource.Success(listData))


        }

}
```

`getEventsList` is in my `WordInfoRepositoryImpl` class in my `data layer` here I am pulling data from internet using jsoap

**WordInfoRepository**

```
interface WordInfoRepository {

     fun getEventsList(): Flow<Resource<MutableList<ExtractedData>>>

}
```

this is the interface that I reference `wordInforepositoryImpl` in the data layer in my interface `domain layer`

**GetWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase**

```
class GetWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase@Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WordInfoRepository
){


     operator fun invoke() : Flow<Resource<MutableList<ExtractedData>>> {

        return repository.getEventsList()


    }
    
}
```

`GetWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase` is my usecase in my `domain layer`

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MostUsedWordScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase: GetWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase
) : ViewModel() {


    private var searchJob: Job? = null

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(MostUsedWordState())
    val state: State<MostUsedWordState> = _state

    init {

        fetchData()
        
    }

    private fun fetchData()  {

        searchJob?.cancel()

        searchJob = viewModelScope.launch(IO) {

            getWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase().onEach { result ->

                when (result) {

                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        _state.value = state.value.copy(
                            mostWordUsedItems = result.data ?: mutableListOf(),
                            isLoading = false

                        )
                    }

                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        _state.value = state.value.copy(
                            mostWordUsedItems = result.data ?: mutableListOf(),
                            isLoading = false
                        )
                    }

                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        _state.value = state.value.copy(
                            mostWordUsedItems = result.data ?: mutableListOf(),
                            isLoading = true
                        )
                    }
                }


            }

        }


    }


}
```

**MostUsedWordScreen**

```
@Composable
fun MostUsedWordScreen(viewModel: MostUsedWordScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    val state = viewModel.state.value
    println("state --- >>> "+state.mostWordUsedItems)
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        items(state.mostWordUsedItems.size) { i ->
            val wordInfo = state.mostWordUsedItems[i]
            if(i > 0) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            }
            MostUsedWordItem(word = wordInfo)
            if(i < state.mostWordUsedItems.size - 1) {
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }


}

@Composable
fun MostUsedWordItem(word : ExtractedData ) {

   // println("this is MostUsedWordItem")


    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(5.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()) {


     Text(text = word.word,
     modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp),
     textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
     fontSize = 18.sp,
     )


    }


}
```

It is included in the `MostUsedWordScreenViewModel` and `MostUsedWordScreen` presententation layer

Where I `println("state --- >>> "+state.mostWordUsedItems)` in `MostUsedWordScreen`, the state console shows as empty like this `System.out: state --- >>> []`

I tried to explain as detailed as I can, I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flow doesn't do anything until you call a terminal operator on it. You called `onEach`, which is not a terminal operator. You should use `collect`. Or you can avoid the nesting inside a launch block by using `onEach` and `launchIn`, which does the same thing as launching a coroutine and calling `collect()` on the flow. You don't need to specify Dispatchers.IO here because nothing in your Flow is blocking. You correctly wrapped the blocking call in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, and the warning is a false positive. That's a well-known bug in their compiler inspection.

```
searchJob = getWordsAndMeaningsOnTheInternetUseCase().onEach { result ->

    when (result) {

        is Resource.Success -> {
            _state.value = state.value.copy(
                mostWordUsedItems = result.data ?: mutableListOf(),
                isLoading = false
            )
        }

        is Resource.Error -> {
            _state.value = state.value.copy(
                mostWordUsedItems = result.data ?: mutableListOf(),
                isLoading = false
            )
        }

        is Resource.Loading -> {
            _state.value = state.value.copy(
                mostWordUsedItems = result.data ?: mutableListOf(),
                isLoading = true
            )
        }
    }

}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

By the way, you need to move your `emit(Success...)` inside your `try` block. The way it is now, when there is an error, the error will immediately get replaced by a Success with empty list.

Side note, I recommend avoiding passing MutableLists around between classes. You have no need for them and it's a code smell. Sharing mutable state between classes is error-prone. I don't think there is any justification for using a `Flow<MutableList>` instead of a `Flow<List>`.

You rarely even need a MutableList locally in a function. For example, you could have done in your try block:

```
val listData = List(eventsSize - 1) {
    val row = rows[it + 1]
    val cols = row.select("td")
    val word = cols[0].text()
    val meaning = cols[1].text()

    ExtractedData(i,word,meaning)
}
emit(Resource.Success(listData))
```

Comment: yes I did what you said and understand but it gives the following error on this line  val word = cols[0].text() IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: okey I solved the issue I converted the List you defined back to mutableList and added accordingly. I iterated with for loop just like I did in my own code and solved the problem. Thank you for everthing. But why am I getting IndexOutOfBoundsException error when I try to run your code.

Comment: Oh, I see you were starting your iteration at 1 instead of 0 like mine does. I don’t know your backing code to know what’s going on there. See updated version.